# Is it possible for an object inside a variable array to have 2 values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

I want my variable array (in JavaScript) to have 2 values: a quote on it, and a true or false value.
This is the part of the code preferable to put it in:

```
var q = new Array()



q[0]='There are some people who live in a dream world, and there are some who face reality; and then there are those who turn one into the other. <i>-By Douglas Everett</i>'

q[1]='Whether you think you can or whether you think you can\'t, you\'re right! <i>-Henry Ford</i>'

q[2]='I know of no more encouraging fact than the unquestionable ability of man to elevate his life by conscious endeavor. <i>-Henry David Thoreau</i>'

q[3]='Do not let what you cannot do interfere with what you can do. <i>-John Wooden</i>'
```

That's one of many quotes that I have (soon to be trivia, I borrowed some code from another site to generate one of these randomly.)
I want, for instance, q[3] to be a quote *and* a true or false value.

Is this possible? Any suggestions on how I should do it otherwise?

I'm a beginner scripter, so sorry if this is an obvious question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use object literals with a property to hold the quote and another to hold the boolean. So, for example:

```
var q = []; // NEVER use new Array() and ALWAYS put a semicolon at the end of lines.

q[0] = {
    quote: 'There are some people who live in a dream world, and there are some who face reality; and then there are those who turn one into the other. <i>-By Douglas Everett</i>',
    someValue: true
};

// ...

alert(q[0].quote); // There are some people...
alert(q[0].someValue); // true
```

Comment: All of your answers were very useful, and very fast. I found this one to be thorough and neat, thanks, minitech!

Comment: I would not say "NEVER use new Array()", it actually has a lot more to do with style. [] is more terse and easier to read, but nothing wrong with using new Array().

Comment: just curious.. what is the down side of using new Array() vs []?

Comment: @arturnt: Yeah, actually, there is stuff wrong with using `new Array`. `new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` but `new Array(5)` is `[,,,,]`. Plus, `Array` can be redefined to be any function; `[]` will always give you an array.

Comment: @AJP too - see above comment.

Comment: The redefine is true, but the other one is a moot point. new Array(5) by definition creates an array of length 5. new Array(1,2,3,4..) creates an array with those elements, that's predictable and by spec. It's like having two different constructors in any language. Not sure what is wrong with that.

Comment: @arturnt: It can be incredibly confusing. There is no good reason to ever use `new Array(element1, element2, elementN...)` over `[element1, element2, elementN...]` and if you're using `new Array(nElements)` then it's probably either 1) pre-optimization or 2) a hacky way of repeating a string. Repeating a string in that way might be okay, but the pre-optimization is usually unnecessary and can only serve to confuse future editors of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, If I follow you, what you want is an array of objects:

```
[{flag: true, text: "If you choose the red pill..."},...]
```

Does that make sense?

The key is that you want a JS object on every element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Make it an array in its own right.

```
q[3] = ['My string....', true];
```

Then use `q[3][0]` to access "My string...." and `q[3][1]` to access the Boolean value.

---

As a side note, when you create an array, you should use the shorthand `[]` notation instead of `new Array()`:

```
var q = [];
```

Comment: I wince every time I see that... it leads to magic array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested arrays.

```
q[0] = ['Some quote',true];
```

Then `q[0][0]` is the quote and `q[0][1]` is the true/false value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = new Array()



q[0]= ['There are some people who live in a dream world, and there are some who face reality; and then there are those who turn one into the other. <i>-By Douglas Everett</i>', true]

q[1]=['Whether you think you can or whether you think you can\'t, you\'re right! <i>-Henry Ford</i>', false]

q[2]=['I know of no more encouraging fact than the unquestionable ability of man to elevate his life by conscious endeavor. <i>-Henry David Thoreau</i>', true]

q[3]=['Do not let what you cannot do interfere with what you can do. <i>-John Wooden</i>', false]

if (q[3][1]) {
    print q[3][0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use an object literal for that.  Something like:

```
var q = [];

q[0]= {Question: 'There are some people who live in a dream world, and there are some who face reality; and then there are those who turn one into the other. <i>-By Douglas Everett</i>', Answer: true};
q[1]= {Question: 'Whether you think you can or whether you think you can\'t, you\'re right! <i>-Henry Ford</i>', Answer: true};
q[2]= {Question: 'I know of no more encouraging fact than the unquestionable ability of man to elevate his life by conscious endeavor. <i>-Henry David Thoreau</i>', Answer: false};
q[3]= {Question: 'Do not let what you cannot do interfere with what you can do. <i>-John Wooden</i>', Answer: false};

window.alert(q[1].Question);
window.alert(q[1].Answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways of doing it, here are three:

```
var q = [];
q.push("Quote#1");
q.push(true);
q.push("Quote#2");
q.push(false);

for(var i = 0; i < q.length-1; i++) {
    console.log(q[i], q[i+1]);
}
```

or

```
var q = [];
q.push({quote: "Quote#1", flag: true});
q.push({quote: "Quote#2", flag: false});
for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    console.log(q[i].quote, q[i].flag);
}
```

or

```
var q = [];
q.push(["Quote#1", true]);
q.push(["Quote#2", false]);
for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    console.log(q[i][0], q[i][1]);
}
```